# $(iframe) showing null, it show object after inspect to iframe,

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sharepoint

I want to access element which is available in iframe , iframe render 3rd party website, 
i am getting null value of `$('iframe')` every time, and when i inspect element to particular element of iframe after it  `$('iframe')` shows object and i can access the desired element and manipulate it , untile i can't access to that desired element.
my question is how can i access to that iframe element .

Answer (score 1):

Try to change URL using attr function of jquery. and there is some change in selector too.

```
$("iframeId").contents().find("img.ms-dlgCloseBtnImg").attr("src","New Image URL");
```

Comment: are you able to change from console??

Comment: please check 4th image from top, the resule of  $("img.ms-dlgCloseBtnImg"),

Comment: can you try $(document).find("img.ms-dlgCloseBtnImg").attr........??
try first in console.

Comment: I found the element, please check 4th image , how I get element

Comment: so that means you selector not fount. You have to find it by iframe element
$("iframeId").contents().find("img.ms-dlgCloseBtnImg").attr....

Answer (score 0):

Try by taking Id or class name and assign the image path on popup load using ready function. Hope so it will work.

Comment: i have checked this , but element is not get property, because of Iframe, ,